# method doesn't return auxiliary variable in Java

Tags: java, sudoku

I'm trying to write a method that checks if a Sudoku puzzle has a unique solution and if true then return the puzzle with the spaces to solve it.

Here's the class which generates it:

```
public class Sudoku {

    private SudokuGen sudoku;
    private boolean isUnique;

    public Sudoku(){
        this.isUnique = false;
        while (!this.isUnique){
            this.setSudoku(createUniqueSolution());
        }
        this.sudoku.getMyboard().showSudokuMatrix();
    }

    private SudokuGen createUniqueSolution(){
        SudokuGen auxSudoku = new SudokuGen();
        this.setSudoku(auxSudoku);
        this.sudoku.getMyboard().showSudokuMatrix();
        Position availableMove = auxSudoku.getFirstAvailableMove();
        while (availableMove != null){
            int row,col;
            row = availableMove.getX();
            col = availableMove.getY();
            Integer value = auxSudoku.getValidvalue(row, col, 0);
            auxSudoku.makeMove(row, col, value);
            auxSudoku.loadValidvalues();
            availableMove = auxSudoku.getFirstAvailableMove();
        }
        if (auxSudoku.getSolved()){

            System.out.println("Unique solution");
            this.isUnique = true;
            return this.getSudoku();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Solution is not unique");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setSudoku(SudokuGen sudoku){
        this.sudoku = sudoku;
    }

    public SudokuGen getSudoku(){
        return (this.sudoku);
    }

}
```

SudokuGen returns a generated puzzle which I don't know if the solution is unique or not. So I call the createUniqueSolution to check it.

First it creates auxSudoku and saves it, then it starts checking if the solution is unique using the auxSudoku puzzle.

- availableMove: gets the first cell which has 1 candidate, if there's no candidate it returns null.
- value: takes the candidate for the given cell.
- .makeMove: plays the candidate, then I update the candidates after using it.

Then I get the next candidate calling availableMove again, until it's null.

So in short, my question is why this.sudoku is modified if I used an auxiliary variable. Thank you in advance.

Here's the output of the code:

```
    212 238 0 0 175 372 311 0 103 
    0 0 0 238 0 103 312 372 0 
    0 372 0 0 212 0 238 175 0 
    0 312 0 0 372 311 212 10 0 
    372 0 10 0 238 0 103 312 0 
    0 212 0 0 0 0 372 311 0 
    311 0 0 372 10 175 0 0 312 
    312 0 238 311 0 212 175 0 0 
    24 0 372 312 0 0 10 0 0 
    Solution is not unique

    0 100 49 71 185 0 0 262 178 
    0 71 262 0 300 49 0 100 257 
    0 0 177 100 262 0 71 0 0 
    0 185 300 262 71 100 178 0 0 
    0 0 0 177 49 0 0 0 0 
    0 0 178 300 257 185 0 71 0 
    0 262 0 185 0 300 0 178 0 
    0 177 0 0 178 71 0 185 0 
    71 0 185 0 0 0 49 0 300 
    Solution is not unique

    284 0 0 0 0 193 25 179 0 
    32 25 193 179 284 0 0 0 0 
    0 0 0 92 25 0 296 0 284 
    0 32 296 0 0 0 0 0 179 
    193 0 0 0 92 0 32 296 84 
    0 179 284 0 296 371 193 0 92 
    0 284 32 0 371 0 0 92 0 
    296 92 371 25 179 0 0 0 193 
    179 0 84 296 0 0 371 0 0
```

Unique solution

```
    284 296 92 371 84 193 25 179 32 
    32 25 193 179 284 296 92 84 371 
    371 84 179 92 25 32 296 193 284 
    92 32 296 84 193 25 284 371 179 
    193 371 25 284 92 179 32 296 84 
    84 179 284 32 296 371 193 25 92 
    25 284 32 193 371 84 179 92 296 
    296 92 371 25 179 284 84 32 193 
    179 193 84 296 32 92 371 284 25
```

The last output is printed by the constructor.

Updated class

```
public class Sudoku {

    private SudokuGen sudoku;

    public Sudoku(){

        SudokuGen auxSudoku = new SudokuGen();

        while (!createUniqueSolution(auxSudoku)){
            auxSudoku = new SudokuGen();
        }
        this.sudoku.getMyboard().showSudokuMatrix();
    }

    private boolean createUniqueSolution(SudokuGen sudoku){

        this.sudoku = new SudokuGen(sudoku);
        this.sudoku.getMyboard().showSudokuMatrix();
        Position availableMove = sudoku.getFirstAvailableMove();
        while (availableMove != null){
            int row,col;
            row = availableMove.getX();
            col = availableMove.getY();
            Integer value = sudoku.getValidvalue(row, col, 0);
            sudoku.makeMove(row, col, value);
            sudoku.loadValidvalues();
            availableMove = sudoku.getFirstAvailableMove();
        }
        if (sudoku.getSolved()){

            System.out.println("Unique solution");
            return true;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Solution is not unique");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void setSudoku(SudokuGen sudoku){
        this.sudoku = sudoku;
    }

    public SudokuGen getSudoku(){
        return (this.sudoku);
    }

}
```

And the copy constructor for SudokuGen:

```
public SudokuGen(SudokuGen sudoku){
    this.genboard = sudoku.genboard;
    this.lockedCells = sudoku.lockedCells;
    this.mutableCells = sudoku.mutableCells;
    this.mutable = sudoku.mutable;
    this.myboard = sudoku.myboard;
    this.Solved = sudoku.Solved;
    this.validvalues = sudoku.validvalues;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "auxiliary variable"?

Comment: auxSudoku is my auxiliary variable, and saved before processing it.

Comment: Why are you so surprised that `this.sudoku` got set? You called the setter! `this.setSudoku(auxSudoku)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method setSudoku() does not create a copy of the SudokuGen object, but rather attaches the existing object to a parent.

What you want is to create a copy constructor for the class SudokuGen so that you can change the line `this.sudoku = sudoku;` to something like `this.sudoku = new SudokuGen (sudoku);`

Comment: I've created the copy constructor and it stills doesn't copy it. I'll add another reply with the updated code.

Comment: @SantiagoRosales: You may need to create a 'deep' copy constructor that creates a fresh copy of each object all the way down the chain. If your copy constructor merely adds the reference for one object to the new object, then changes to one will be reflected in the other (since it references the same object).

Comment: I ended up using Kryo to copy the actual values of the object.